# Main method with generic parameter; why does it work?

Tags: java, generics, program-entry-point, type-inference

```
public static <T extends String> void main(T[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World!");
}
```

I was curious to see if the above snippet of code would compile and run successfully, and it does!  However, I also wondered what would happen if `T extends String` was replaced with `T extends String & AutoClosable`; `String` does not implement `AutoClosable`, so I didn't expect this to run successfully, but it still does!

```
public static <T extends String & AutoCloseable> void main(T[] args) {
    System.out.println("This still works!");
}
```

So my question is, why does this still run successfully?

**Notes**:

- I'm testing this with Java 10.0.1
- Intellij doesn't play nice with this method because it doesn't see it as an entry point to the program; I haven't tested it with other IDEs.
- You're also able to pass arguments using the command-line just as you would with any other program.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is because a type parameter has a bound:

```
<T extends String>                  =>  String

<T extends String & AutoCloseable>  =>  String & AutoCloseable
```

And the bytecode after erasure is the same as for the regular `main` declaration in both cases:

```
public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

[JLS §4.4. Type Variables:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4)

> The order of types in a bound is only significant in that **the erasure
>   of a type variable is determined by the first type in its bound**, and
>   that a class type or type variable may only appear in the first
>   position.

Comment: @Li357 only the first bound contributes to the erased type.

Comment: Interestingly, after adding `args[0].close();` and the requisite `throws Exception` declaration, the program still compiles without any warnings, and fails at runtime because `String` cannot be cast to `AutoCloseable`.

Comment: @wchargin: Good point! But I don't think it's *too* surprising that your compiler doesn't emit any warnings for this, since it's legitimate to define a `main` method that isn't even intended as an entry point. (In my experience, no compiler emits a warning for something like `public static void main()`.) `main` is invoked in a way that's effectively like reflection, circumventing any aspect of the static type system that's not reified at runtime.

Comment: @wchargin You don't call the `main` method explicitly; if you try to do it from your code (passing a parameter that doesn't implement an `AutoCloseable` interface), then you will get an `incompatible bounds` compiler error.

Comment: Your answer, despite being correct, needs more explanation.

Comment: @Mohammad If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask me!

Comment: @Oleksandr Thank you. Actually, I don't have any. But other readers may don't understand why compiling such a `main` method is possible.  They may don't know what *erasure* is, or how the JVM finds the `main` method.